# How to get a file from SharePoint by using Selenium in Databricks (Azure)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, sharepoint, databricks

I've a code where I'm trying to develop an algorithm with web scraping thats be able to go into a SharePoint URL, make click in "Descargar" button in order to download a file and storage it into a temporary path, and then, convert it in a Data Frame to transform it with python. I'm using this method since I just have viewer permissions and I haven't password, ID or file id.

So, the problem comes when I try to use By.CLASS_NAME method. When I go to inspect the object (button) where I want to click, don't get anything that can fits the methods described. The process I'm following to get the Class (Also I've been trying to use By.NAME, By.ID and By.XPATH but does not works):

[image]

Down below my try using By.CLASS_NAME method:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager # downloads v 32.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

mypath = '/tmp/head_count_data/'
service = Service(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install()) 

options = Options()
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", mypath)
options.headless = False
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.binary_location = '/tmp/firefox/firefox'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=service)
url = "https://sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FSite%2FShared%20Documents%2F01%2E%20File%2F2020&viewid=d7ce04e1%2D44e3%2D4ff1%2Dac16%2D83b76b6a9d7f"
driver.get(url)
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ms-ContextualMenu-itemText label-381")
dropdown.click()
time.sleep(60)
```

HTML Object:

```html
<button name="Descargar" data-automationid="downloadCommand" class="ms-ContextualMenu-link root-371" aria-label="Descargar" aria-posinset="8" aria-setsize="13" aria-disabled="false" role="menuitem" tabindex="0"><div class="ms-ContextualMenu-linkContent linkContent-375"><span class="ms-ContextualMenu-itemText label-381">Descargar</span></div></button>
<span class="ms-ContextualMenu-itemText label-381">Descargar</span>
<div class="ms-ContextualMenu-linkContent linkContent-375"><span class="ms-ContextualMenu-itemText label-381">Descargar</span></div>
```

The error is the next one:

[image]

Do you have any idea why I get this issue and how to fix it? What's the proper way to get Class from a object in SharePoint?

Note: I've test this scenario with other web sites by and it works (in Databricks as well).

```
'
```

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the error is this line

```
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ms-ContextualMenu-itemText label-381")
```

You are using `By.CLASS_NAME` but passing in 2 classes, `ms-ContextualMenu-itemText` and `label-381` when it's expecting only a single class. That's causing the error. You can tell that because it's converting the expected single class to a CSS selector,

```
.ms-ContextualMenu-itemText label-381
^ the period in CSS selector syntax indicates a class
```

The problem is the space and the rest of the class after the first class.

Instead convert this into a CSS selector,

```
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.ms-ContextualMenu-itemText.label-381")
```

My concern here is the `381` number after the label in the class. I don't know how stable that number is. You may be better off changing to an XPath and use the contained text of "Descargar", e.g.

```
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Descargar']")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same error, but thanks

Comment: You can't have received the same error because the locator is different. Are you clicking to open the menu that contains "Descargar" first? Selenium won't click on an element that isn't visible.